# Punctuating a sentence which is a question followed by statement

Tags: question-mark

Which is best?

Do we need to walk to the supermarket, as we have a car?

OR

Do we need to walk to the supermarket, as we have a car.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest to change to:

Since we have car, do we need to walk to the supermarket?

Answer (score -1):

First of all, placing the question mark after the "as" clause sounds like you should walk to the supermarket *because* you have a car (although a lot depends on intonation and stress).

Consider:

> Do we need to walk to the supermarket, as we **don't** have a car?

(I see this construction as definitely a question, thus requiring a question mark somewhere, which rules out your second example).

To avoid this, I would restructure, placing the question mark directly after the question clause, in which case the clarification (in this case, the reason you are asking), is separated.

> Do we need to walk? As we have a car.

(Note that sentence fragments are best used only informally).

or

> As we have a car, do we need to walk?

Otherwise, you can rephrase, using "seeing as" or similar, and be able to keep the structure of your first example:

> Do we need to walk, **seeing as** we have a car?