# How should I correctly write this question?

Tags: syntactic-analysis, question-mark

"Can you provide documentation stating the noise levels, so that we are able to show compliance if we get audited?"
Even though this is a question, I feel like the question mark at the end doesn't seem right. I would've put a full stop at the end but knowing it is a question I have put the question mark there. It could be written as a question and a sentence, "Can you provide documentation? So, that we are able to show compliance." Just wondering how to correctly write as one sentence/question.

Comment: It would help to know the context.  Is this a request in a rental agreement, a letter to some standards technician, a verbal request between two friends, or what?  Among other things, it's not clear why you say "Can you provide" vs "Please provide".

Comment: It was in an email to send to the original equipment manufacturer for a truck that will be going onto site, where there are minimum standards and documentation that is required. "Please provide" could also have been used, no reason for using "can you". I was just asking on this forum out of curiosity.

Comment: "Please provide" is a polite instruction (no question mark), whereas "Can you provide" is ambiguous: it might be an instruction (no politeness; no question mark) or a blunt request (not as polite as *could you* but still ok; use question mark), or a genuine question about capacity to complete the task (factual; question mark).

Comment: The comma might be extraneous, but the question mark is fine where it is.

Comment: ***Can you provide documentation stating the noise level for us to produce/show the compliance in case of an audit?***

Comment: You could say "Please provide ..." rather than "Can you provide ..."

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Do you use a question mark when a sentence starts as a question but then turns into a statement?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/101591/do-you-use-a-question-mark-when-a-sentence-starts-as-a-question-but-then-turns-i) ...  Does this? [Punctuating a sentence which is a question followed by statement](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/162794/punctuating-a-sentence-which-is-a-question-followed-by-statement) However, here, the 'so that ...' clause may be considered to modify the question, requiring a terminal question mark.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Do you use a question mark when a sentence starts as a question but then turns into a statement?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/101591/do-you-use-a-question-mark-when-a-sentence-starts-as-a-question-but-then-turns-i)

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it does not benefit the site, is POB, and appears to be the only time we have seen the OP on EL&U...they just 
never came back. This question is bloat.

Answer (score -1):

> "Can you provide documentation stating the noise levels, so that we
>   are able to show compliance if we get audited?"

I would reverse the order, putting the question last.

> In order to demonstrate compliance in case of an audit, can you
>   provide noise level documentation?

Comment: The reordering needs 'So that we can ...' or 'To enable us to ...'.