# Questions with an explanation

Tags: questions

What is the correct punctuation for a question that in itself contains an explanation as to why it was asked? For example:

- "Is the book long - I might read it just for fun?"
- "Is this dress new - I really like it?"

Should there be a comma or a semicolon instead of a dash? Is it considered bad style to break up such sentences into two? Like this:

- "Is the book long? I might read it just for fun."

The two-sentence version changes the rhythm, it adds a break between the question and the explanation. Sometimes you want to say (or read) it in a single breath.

Is there a special name for these type of questions?

Comment: It seems to me that regardless of whether the two parts are tightly tied together, the second part is still not a question. It's a statement. So it doesn't make sense to include it in the question, punctuated by a question mark. Two sentences would seem like the only logical option.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Punctuating a sentence which is a question followed by statement](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/162794/punctuating-a-sentence-which-is-a-question-followed-by-statement) And better, @Jon Hanna's answer at [Do you use a question mark {and if so where} when a sentence starts as a question but then turns into a statement?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/101591/do-you-use-a-question-mark-when-a-sentence-starts-as-a-question-but-then-turns-i)

Comment: @EdwinAshworth No, but very related, thanks.

Comment: 'Can you explain this to me? I don't understand the second part.' is a near duplicate. The solution is to re-order or use two sentences.